# Plot ties originally from two different networks in a merged network

Tags: r, networking, plot, igraph

I want to merge two networks with exactly the same nodes. In the merged network, I want to plot the edges from different original networks in different colors. Below are what I have done using igraph and the problems I encountered:

I first set names to the two original graphs, and types to the edges.

```
g1 = set.graph.attribute(g1, "name", “AA”)
E(g1)$type = “A”
g2 = set.graph.attribute(g2, "name", “BB”)
E(g2)$type = “B”
```

Then, I unite the two graphs.

```
g = graph.union(g1, g2, byname=TRUE)
```

Here I got an error:

> Error in .igraph.graph.union.or.intersection("R_igraph_union", ..., byname = byname,  : 
>     Some graphs are not named

In fact, both two original graphs are named. This error here is a bit strange. I go ahead with the following codes instead. Now it works.

```
g = graph.union(g1, g2, byname="auto")
```

These are some results I got:

```
E(g1)
```

> Edge sequence:
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVZUl.jpg) 5 -- 1 [2] 6 -- 1 [3] 4 -- 2 [4] 6 -- 5

```
E(g2)
```

> Edge sequence:
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVZUl.jpg) 3 -- 2 [2] 6 -- 2 [3] 5 -- 4 [4] 6 -- 4 [5] 6 -- 5

```
E(g)
```

> Edge sequence:
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVZUl.jpg) 6 -- 5 [2] 6 -- 4 [3] 5 -- 4 [4] 6 -- 2 [5] 4 -- 2 [6] 3 -- 2 [7] 6 -- 1 [8] 5 -- 1

```
E(g1)$type
```

> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVZUl.jpg) "A" "A" "A" "A"

```
E(g2)$type
```

> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVZUl.jpg) "B" "B" "B" "B" "B"

```
E(g)$type_1
```

> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVZUl.jpg) "A" NA  NA  NA  "A" NA  "A" "A"

```
E(g)$type_2
```

> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVZUl.jpg) "B" "B" "B" "B" NA  "B" NA  NA

I try to plot the edges with type "A" in red, and edges with type "B" in blue, using the following codes.

```
plot(g, edge.color=ifelse(E(g)$type_1=="A","red","blue"))
```

[image]

It just plots the edges with type "B". Why it does plot the edges with type "A"? What's wrong with these codes?

I am also curious if there is a way to keep the name of the edge attribute of the united graph as "type". Here it automatic changes the name into "type_1" and "type_2", which are two attributes. If keeping the name, some edges will be with type "A", come will be "B", and some will be both "A" and "B" (such as edge 5 -- 6 in this case). This might make it easier to plot the edges in different colors.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: the first error happened because I guess your graphs doesn't have name attribute for its vertices .try something like this  for both graph and specify the name attribute of the vertices,`V(g1)$name<-V(g1)`

Comment: I tied. It works. Thanks a lot. When uniting the two graphs, it still dose not merge the attribute of edges. It creates "type_1" and "type_2".

Comment: I am also looking for a way or function to that,but if you want to have just one edges between each pair nodes. you could do it by yourself `E(g)$type <- E(g1)$type_1 + E(g2)$type_2`, and then remove `type_1`, `type_2`then specify the one with both type by the third color.(although I do not check it for character type attribute)

Comment: and one other things which I forgot to add, if your graphs has the same nodes, by `V(g1)$name<-V(g1)` and `V(g2)$name<-V(g2)` you may end up two different name for the same vertex, to get the desired name, you could use `permute.vertices()` see this [link](http://igraph.org/r/doc/permute.vertices.html)